# How to color the inside of a box

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, color

I haven't found any explanation on how to color the inside of an object (in my case a box for a perfume) especially when the box has more than one layer (I don't remember seeing a video on YouTube of boxes with a colored inside, I saw that their insides is identical to their outsides, either by choice or they failed to apply a different color/texture to the inside).

I have applied the basic method to apply the color inside but obviously, no change can be seen. [image: screenshot]

The blender file :

[image]

Comment: Simplest way would be to apply the Solidify modifier then temporarily disable the Armature modifier for convenience then apply one colour to the top faces and another to the bottom ones.

Comment: When you delete the file you're linking to, please delete the link as well.

Comment: and please share files via https://blend-exchange.com/ .thx.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few ways:

- If you have a single surface, you can define a shader for backfaces(That's "Geometry" node there in the Shader Editor that has Backfacing output):

[image]

- If you have an actual realistic box made of thick material, you can simply assign a different material to inside faces:

[image]

- If you use Solidify modifier, you can have more than one material slot, and adjust modifier material index for offset part and for the rim. By the way - some other modifiers have similar functionality for geometry they generate. Material slot indices start at 0(the first one is number 0, the second one 1 and so on).

[image]

- You could also have a single material for a double sided box with UVs mapped for outside and inside and define material properties using textures.

Answer (score 1):

If the backfacing setup you made doesn't result in a white material being visible, it probably means there are no backfaces visible on your model. I suspect your object has actual thickness instead. There are many other ways to create masks in Blender, you could very well create a color attribute on the object (data properties) and fill the inside faces with white, then use that attribute in the shader editor (attribute node) to drive the mix shader.